# Check if value is between a range of numbers

Tags: java, android, integer, compare

I am trying to check if values from a text box are between 4 and 80 but cant
I can do this but its not what i need

```
 final String checkage = age.getText().toString();
    if(checkage.equals(4)   || checkage.equals(80) ) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You must be older than 4 and younger than 80", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
}
```

Comment: Try to use that where `i` its your number`if (i >= 4 && i <= 80) `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
final String checkage = age.getText().toString();
int value = Integer.parseInt(checkage);

if(value >= 4 && value <= 80) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "You must be older than 4 and younger than 80", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return;
}
```

'**||**' won't be useful for you in this case.

Comment: thanks a lot =) that worked.. but again am getting down-voted. what did i do wrong this time ?  was I not str8 to point ?

Comment: Maybe people give you down-voted because you have not searched in google before asking... you need to search first and later if you have any problem only ask here @user3656666 (accept that question as correct to the other users)

Comment: I did search. ye I will accept it as correct as soon as the system allows me. 4 mins left

Comment: @user3656666 then you need to do a deeper search and not give up so quickly in your quest. (do not put abbreviations such as `"str8"` people from other countries might not understand). Don't worry for down-voted now, it's normal the first times.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for everything , ill keep all those in mind next time

Answer (score 0):

your logic is wrong. you need to do something like this.

```
final String checkage = age.getText().toString();
if (i > 4 && i < 80) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "You must be older than 4 and younger than 80", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```